# how do I create a subtitle box that resizes and comes out letter by letter?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZQMx.png)i want to create subtitles in a grey transparent box that auto resizes, also the text comes out letter by letter, disappears and the next dialogue is printed out until everything has been printed out, embedded is the prototype im aiming for

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="subtitle.css">
</head>
<h1> Subtitle Test </h1>
<div id="subtitle"></div>


<script>
  // Test set of subtitles which demonstrate the system
  var subtitles = [
    ["This is a test of the subtitle system", 4000],
    ["to display a set of subtitles pass in a 2D array into the displaySubtitles() method where the first index is the text to display", 10000],
    ["And the second index is the time that specific subtitle should be up for in miliseconds", 10000],
    ["After it has gone through the entire set of subtitles the text and background will disappear until its called again", 10000],
  ]
  // This is the paragraph element that we print the text to
  var subtitleText = document.createElement("p");
  // This is the subtitle text that is displayed
  var subTitleNode = document.createTextNode("");
  // A buffer for storing the string we display, its updated over time to give
  // a scrolling effect
  var textBuffer = "";

  // Add the text to the paragraph node
  subtitleText.append(subTitleNode);

  // Function is used to initialize the subtitle system, you pass into it
  // a subtitles 2D array of the form [["text",time]] where time is how long
  // that subtitle text should stay up for
  function displaySubtitles(subtitles) {
    // The total elapsed time, must be set to 0 used to time subtitles
    var total = 0;
    // Makes the subtitles visible in case they were set to invisible
    document.getElementById("subtitle").style.display = "flex";
    // For each item in the subtitles 2D array
    for (let i = 0; i <= subtitles.length; i++) {

      // If all of the subtitles have been displayed, then set it to be hidden
      if (i == subtitles.length) {
        setTimeout(hideSubtitle, total);
      } else {
        // Show the current subtitle and increment the time to further delay
        // the next set
        setTimeout(showSubtitle, total, subtitles[i][0], subtitles[i][1]);
        total += subtitles[i][1];
      }
    }
  }

  // Helper function which is called on every string in the 2D array,
  // responsible for splitting the string up and calling the updateBuffer()
  // method at the correct time intervals
  function showSubtitle(string, delay) {
    // How many total characters in the required string
    var sizeOfBuffer = string.length;
    // Leave at 0, used to time the displaying of subtitles
    var totalTaken = 0;
    // How long to wait after the subtitles have been fully shown
    // Make sure its not larger than any of the subtitles delay
    var timeToWait = 2000;
    // Finds out how long to wait for each indivigual character to be shown
    var increments = (delay - timeToWait) / sizeOfBuffer;
    // Resets the text buffer once all the characters have been shown
    setTimeout(function() {
      textBuffer = "";
    }, delay - 20);
    // For each character in the text
    for (let i = 0; i < sizeOfBuffer; i++) {
      // Add that character to the buffer and update the elapsed time
      setTimeout(updateBuffer, totalTaken, string.charAt(i));
      totalTaken += increments;
    }
  }

  // This is a helper function called by showSubtitle() it takes in a 
  // character and puts it into the buffer, it then causes the text
  // node in the html page to display the buffers contents giving
  // the illusion of typing text
  function updateBuffer(string) {
    textBuffer = textBuffer.concat(string);
    subTitleNode.nodeValue = textBuffer;
  }

  function hideSubtitle() {
    // Removes the display from the subtitle making it invisible
    document.getElementById("subtitle").style.display = "none";
  }

  const element = document.getElementById("subtitle");
  element.appendChild(subtitleText);

  displaySubtitles(subtitles);
</script>
```

im trying to use the above code to use as a template but im struggling with the styling of the box on css

i want the box to resize as the dialogue comes out but ive not been able to do so, below is what my css so far but i dont need a textarea for user input just a box that prints text but im unsure how to edit the code to do that

```
  *{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: gray;
    opacity: 1;
}

.wrapper{
    width: 470px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 25px 25px 30px;
}

.wrapper h2{
    color: grey;
    font-size: 28px;
    text-align: center;
}

.wrapper textarea{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    outline: none;
    resize: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-color: #bfbfbf;
}

textarea:is(:focus, :valid){
    border-width: 2px;
    padding: 14px;
    border-color: grey;
}
```

Comment: What is the issue?  the `p` size increases as I see it.

Comment: What have you tried exactly? And what is the exact error you need help with?

Comment: is this chatGPTv2? :)

Answer (score 2):

I would toggle a show class to display the subtitle.

```js
function displaySubtitles(subtitles) {
  subtitleEl.classList.add('show');
}
```

```js
function hideSubtitle() {
  subtitleEl.classList.remove('show');
}
```

If you use Flexbox (`display: flex`), you can have the container dynamically resize for you.

**Edit:** I fixed the initial display CSS

```js
const subtitleEl = document.querySelector('#subtitle');

// Test set of subtitles which demonstrate the system
const subtitles = [
  ["This is a test of the subtitle system", 4000],
  ["to display a set of subtitles pass in a 2D array into the displaySubtitles() method where the first index is the text to display", 10000],
  ["And the second index is the time that specific subtitle should be up for in miliseconds", 10000],
  ["After it has gone through the entire set of subtitles the text and background will disappear until its called again", 10000],
]
// This is the paragraph element that we print the text to
const subtitleText = document.createElement("p");
// This is the subtitle text that is displayed
const subtitleNode = document.createTextNode("");
// A buffer for storing the string we display, its updated over time to give
// a scrolling effect
let textBuffer = "";

// Add the text to the paragraph node
subtitleText.append(subtitleNode);

subtitleEl.appendChild(subtitleText);

displaySubtitles(subtitles);

// Function is used to initialize the subtitle system, you pass into it
// a subtitles 2D array of the form [["text",time]] where time is how long
// that subtitle text should stay up for
function displaySubtitles(subtitles) {
  // The total elapsed time, must be set to 0 used to time subtitles
  let total = 0;
  // Makes the subtitles visible in case they were set to invisible
  subtitleEl.classList.add('show');
  // For each item in the subtitles 2D array
  for (let i = 0; i <= subtitles.length; i++) {
    // If all of the subtitles have been displayed, then set it to be hidden
    if (i === subtitles.length) {
      setTimeout(hideSubtitle, total);
    } else {
      // Show the current subtitle and increment the time to further delay
      // the next set
      setTimeout(showSubtitle, total, subtitles[i][0], subtitles[i][1]);
      total += subtitles[i][1];
    }
  }
}

// Helper function which is called on every string in the 2D array,
// responsible for splitting the string up and calling the updateBuffer()
// method at the correct time intervals
function showSubtitle(string, delay) {
  // How many total characters in the required string
  const sizeOfBuffer = string.length;
  // Leave at 0, used to time the displaying of subtitles
  let totalTaken = 0;
  // How long to wait after the subtitles have been fully shown
  // Make sure its not larger than any of the subtitles delay
  const timeToWait = 2000;
  // Finds out how long to wait for each indivigual character to be shown
  const increments = (delay - timeToWait) / sizeOfBuffer;
  // Resets the text buffer once all the characters have been shown
  setTimeout(function() {
    textBuffer = "";
  }, delay - 20);
  // For each character in the text
  for (let i = 0; i < sizeOfBuffer; i++) {
    // Add that character to the buffer and update the elapsed time
    setTimeout(updateBuffer, totalTaken, string.charAt(i));
    totalTaken += increments;
  }
}

// This is a helper function called by showSubtitle() it takes in a 
// character and puts it into the buffer, it then causes the text
// node in the html page to display the buffers contents giving
// the illusion of typing text
function updateBuffer(string) {
  textBuffer = textBuffer.concat(string);
  subtitleNode.nodeValue = textBuffer;
}

function hideSubtitle() {
  // Removes the display from the subtitle making it invisible
  subtitleEl.classList.remove('show');
}
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after { box-sizing: border-box; }

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #222;
  color: #EEE;
}

#subtitle {
  display: none;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  max-width: 50vw;
  text-align: center;
}

#subtitle.show {
  display: flex;
}

#subtitle p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<h1>Subtitle Test</h1>
<div id="subtitle"></div>
```